# AudioQueue *Recording* Example Without C++?

Tags: objective-c, ios

For reasons that are hard to understand, since Audio Queue Services are a pure-c wrapper, the only example for recording, SpeakHere:

1. Is a pretty large and interesting working application, which is a lot to parse for an example
2. Includes .cpp files and even some .mm files. For the obj-C programmer that only occasionally uses pure C, this is a big hurdle.

Are there any examples of using AudioQueueServices, especially recording, via a simple example that does not use C++?

Comment: this covers playback, it seems: http://gitorious.org/iosaudioexample#more

Comment: I'm going to attempt to wrap the SpeakHere example as an API. I mean, it does work, after all.